# How to display a picture in JavaScript that can be changed

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension

I am making a sort of simple pet hangman game extension that I made from a tutorial. Most of the extension works fine, but my pictures do not display. I have the picture files as assets.
Here is my js code:

```
const words = [
  'KITTEN',
  'PUPPY',
  'BUNNY',
  'HAMSTER',
  'AXOLOTL',
  'FISH',
  'REPTILE',
  'BIRD'
];

// Define the maximum number of incorrect guesses allowed
const maxWrongGuesses = 5;

let wordToGuess = '';
let guessedLetters = [];
let wrongGuesses = 0;
let imageCount = 1;

// Select random word from the list
function selectRandomWord() {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}

// Initialize the game
function initializeGame() {
  wordToGuess = selectRandomWord();
  guessedLetters = Array(wordToGuess.length).fill('_');
  wrongGuesses = 0;

  // Update the word display
  updateWordDisplay();

  updateKitGraphic();

  // Remove any previously generated buttons
  const lettersContainer = document.querySelector('.letters');
  while (lettersContainer.firstChild) {
  lettersContainer.removeChild(lettersContainer.firstChild);
  }

 // Generate the letter buttons
  for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    const letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = letter;
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      handleGuess(letter);
    });
    lettersContainer.appendChild(button);
  }

  // Clear any previous win/lose message
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector('.message');
  messageContainer.innerText = '';
}

// Update the word display
function updateWordDisplay() {
  const wordContainer = document.querySelector('.word');
  wordContainer.innerText = guessedLetters.join(' ');
}

// Handle a letter guess
function handleGuess(letter) {
  // If the letter has already been guessed, do nothing
  if (guessedLetters.includes(letter)) {
    return;
  }

 // Add the letter to the list of guessed letters
  guessedLetters.forEach((guessedLetter, index) => {
    if (wordToGuess[index] === letter) {
      guessedLetters[index] = letter;
    }
  });

  // If the letter is not in the hidden word, increment the wrong guesses count and update the Kitten Graphic
  if (!wordToGuess.includes(letter)) {
    wrongGuesses++;
    updateKitGraphic();
  }

  // Update the word display
  updateWordDisplay();

  // Check if the game has been won or lost
  checkWinOrLose();
}

function updateKitGraphic() {
  const KitContainer = document.querySelector('.Kit');
  KitContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="images/Kit${imageCount}.png" alt="Kit ${imageCount}">`;
  imageCount++;
}

// Check if the game has been won or lost
function checkWinOrLose() {
  if (guessedLetters.join('') === wordToGuess) {
    const messageContainer = document.querySelector('.message');
    messageContainer.innerText = 'You win!';
    const letterButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.letters button');
    letterButtons.forEach(button => {
      button.disabled = true;
      button.removeEventListener('click', handleGuess);
    });
  } else if (wrongGuesses >= maxWrongGuesses) {
    const messageContainer = document.querySelector('.message');
    messageContainer.innerText = `You lose! The word was "${wordToGuess}".`;
    const KitContainer = document.querySelector('.Kit');
    KitContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="images/gameover.png" alt="gameover">`;
    const letterButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.letters button');
    letterButtons.forEach(button => {
      button.disabled = true;
      button.removeEventListener('click', handleGuess);
    });
  }
}

// Initialize the game when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', initializeGame);
```

The pic simply comes up with the little icon displayed when pictures aren't available and says the name of the picture.

I tried changing how I put the photo up, but it didn't work. I suppose it is how I opened the files and where I saved them that made this happen. Please try and answer my questions if you can!

Muffin123

Comment: which image is not showing , i didn't understand.

Comment: make sure your pictures name is like : kit1 kit2 kit3,
if not then rename them

Comment: The pictures that display the kittens are just showing up as the 'this picture is not available' icon with the name of the image underneath